# How to validate textbox only for spaces?

Tags: asp.net, validation, space, requiredfieldvalidator

I have a tex box in aspx page and i need to validate the text box. How can i do this at server side.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

if(Textbox1.Text=="")
{
    lblError.Text ="Enter required field":
}
```

this is working when user leaves the text box blank. But when he enter white spaces the message is not shown. Is there any solution to this?

Comment: you could add a reg-ex to it, and maybe a range validator will work?

Comment: which .net frame work you are working now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your using .net 4.0 or above than following work.

```
if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Textbox1.Text))
{
      lblError.Text ="Enter required field";
}
```

otherwise you have to check manually...

```
int flag=0;
char[] c=Textbox1.Text.ToCharArray();
for(int i=0;i<c.length;i++)
{
    if(c[i]!=" ")
    {
       flag=1;
       break;
    }
}
if(flag==0 || Textbox1.Text==""|| Textbox1.Text==null)
      lblError.Text ="Enter required field";
```

this will check emptiness .null and whitespaces of TextBox

Comment: if you are using `IsNullOrWhiteSpace` then there is no use to use `IsNullOrEmpty` it is superfluous to use it.

Comment: I think  'IsnullOrWhiteSpace' is enough to check.. It is working fine. Thanks Amit..

Answer (score 0):

server side

use

```
 trim(textbox1.text)==""
```

check like this

```
if(trim(textbox1.text)=="")
   //textbox is blank
```

### Edit 1

I you have to check for space in between words then

```
var words = txtBox.Text.Split(' ');
if(words.Length>0)
 // there are spaces in the textbox
```

### edit 2

Or use [string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/system.string.isnullorwhitespace.aspx)

Comment: it doesnt check space it check only empty textbox.....bcz "" and "   " is diffrent in c#

Comment: Looks like mixture of VB.Net and C# :P

Comment: use @AmitSingh solution it will work use `IsNullOrWhiteSpace` function of string class

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfv" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBox1" 
    ErrorMessage="Enter required field" />
```

try to use required field validator. 
I think this might help you.